# Burning package remapping into dojo build

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojo-build, dojo-1.7

I am developing a set of modules for others to use using dojo 1.7. All modules are AMD modules and using relative paths within the package. My modules will need to be loaded cross domain, and not interfere with or care about the version of dojo running on the page consuming the modules (Let's assume someone is using. If I understand the documentation correctly, I can specify a packing remapping by doing something like this:

```
var dojoConfig = {
    packages: [
        {
            name: "myDojo",
            location: "path/to/my/dojo",
            packageMap: {
                dojo: "myDojo",
                dijit: "myDijit",
                dojox: "myDojox"
            }
        },
        {
            name: "myDijit",
            location: "path/to/my/dijit",
            packageMap: {
                dojo: "myDojo"
            }
        },
        {
            name: "myDojox",
            location: "path/to/my/dojox",
            packageMap: {
                dojo: "myDojo",
                dijit: "myDijit",
                dojox: "myDojox"
            }
        },
        {
            name: "myPackage",
            location: "path/to/my/package",
            packageMap: {
                dojo: "myDojo",
                dijit: "myDijit",
                dojox: "myDojox"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to burn the remapping into a dojo build so that using any module in my package will automatically use my dojo/dijit/dojox modules instead of the ones loaded in the local version of dojo? If so, what would the profile look like? If possible, I would like consumers to be able to do something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="some/differnt/version/of/dojo.js" type="text/javascript" data-dojo-config="config settings"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // For legacy syntax users:
        dojo.registerModulePath("hisPackage", "http://somedomain.com/scripts/myPackage");
        dojo.require("hisPackage.HisModule");

        dojo.ready(function() {
            // do stuff
        });

        // Or for AMD users:
        require(["http://somedomain.com/scripts/myPackage/MyModule"], function(HisModule) {
            // do stuff
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Even if it works it won't be a very elegant hack, but what about rewriting most of your module-IDs as relative paths?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this in your dojoConfig

```
var dojoConfig = { ...
    packages: [
        {name:'dojo',location:'//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.2/dojo/'},
        {name:'dijit',location:'//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.2/dijit/'},
        'dojotut'
    ]
...
}
```